# How to load a flash file in any broswer?

Tags: html, flash

We are trying to load a flash file in a browser from local machine its loading only in Internet Explorer (IE) but not in other browsers. Please suggest me some solution.

Comment: Show the HTML code which you're using to show the flash file. The problem is in there.

Answer (score 0):

Hey mate, you should try SWFObject.

You can download it from here:
http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/downloads/detail?name=swfobject_2_2.zip&can=2&q=

The documentation is here:
http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation

You should put your code here otherwise we can't really help you :)

Rob

Comment: Thank you rob for your quick response.I want to load from the local disk.                              Here is the code:           <body>        
        <object id="flowplayer" width="300" height="200" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.5.swf"
 type="application/x-shockwave-flash">

 <param name="movie" value="E:/SkillMate1/video/zelda.swf" />
 <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />

 <param name="flashvars"
  value='config={"clip":"E:/SkillMate1/video/zelda.swf"}' />
</object>
</body>

Answer (score 0):

here is a basic example for the SWFObject:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Embedding FlowPlayer using SWFObject</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/swfobject.js"></script>
    <meta name="language" content="en" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <!-- SWFObject downloads and documentation: http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function embedFlash()
        {
            var flashvarsObj = {
            };
            //flashvars.config = config;
            var paramsObj = {
                allowScriptAccess: "sameDomain",
                allowFullScreen: "true"
            };
            var attributesObj = {};
            swfobject.embedSWF("swf/test.swf", "flowplayer_container", "300", "200", "10", "swf/expressInstall.swf", flashvarsObj, paramsObj, attributesObj);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="flash_container" style="background-color:#ff0000; width:300px; height:200px;">Your SWF file will be placed here.</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">embedFlash();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can download the swfobject.js file and the expressinstall.swf file from the link I sent you previously.

Good luck, Rob

Comment: Just one more thing. You can pass variables to your embedded flash file by adding them to the flashvarsObj. Also (but I reckon you are aware of it) using "E:/SkillMate1/video/zelda.swf" won't work only on your machine. You should use relative path instead.

Comment: Hi Rob, Thanks for providing code in javascript but we are looking code in jsp without using embed tag.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the unformatted code block you posted in the other answer, your HTML is missing an `<embed>` tag inside the `<object>` tag.  You need both to correctly start the plugin in all browsers.  You can read about this [here](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/415/tn_4150.html).

You might still want to check out [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/), as suggested in the other answer.